# Java program that calls external program behaving asynchronously?

Tags: java, shell, asynchronous, sql-loader

All,

I originally had a shell script that called SQLLoader (Oracles data upload tool).

The problem was that SQLLoader takes a plain text password as input so I decided to build a Java application to call SQLLoader internally passing a decrypted password into the command string.

e.g.

> sqlldr user/pass@DBServer control=../sqlloader.ctl log=sqlloader.log data=mydata.csv

So with my java wrapper it became this in my shell script

```
java -jar sqlloader.jar sqlloader.ctl mydata.csv
```

However a new problem developed when SQLLoader complained there was no file to load. After some head scratching it was discovered that a subsequent command in my shell script seemed to be executing while my java application was still running. Therefore it was behaving asynchronously.

The next command was moving the input file sqlloader was using before it could get a chance to use it. So I put a sleep command in of 20 seconds to give my java application time to run.

```
java -jar sqlloader.jar sqlloader.ctl mydata.csv
echo $?
sleep 20
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "SQLLoader failed during execution, please check the log : " 
        mv mydata.csv

else
    echo "SQLLoader successfully processed file : "
    mv mydata.csv
fi
```

Does anyone know why unix is behaving this way, does Java execute my SQLLoader as a different user/ thread?

This is my java code:

```
    Runtime Rt;
Process Prc;
    Prc = Rt.exec("sqlldr user/decryptedpass@DBServer control=../sqlloader.ctl log=sqlloader.log data=mydata.csv);
system.exit(0);
```

I checked the Runtime Class for anything about it being Asynchronous but couldnt find anything

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Any theories or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing in your code after the exec?

Comment: system.exit(0); is my last line in java program

Comment: This might be off topic, but... What's the intention to encrypt the password? Do you really hardcode the password in Java String like your sample code? If so, hacker can unzip the `jar` file and peek the `.class` file, the password will be just plaintext. Java `Runtime.exec` is low-level and complex to handle, and there should be some simpler way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you look at Runtime.exec again it does specify that it will launch a new process in the specified environment (e.g. independently of the current "environment" or as you put it asynchronously). You should use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to create a [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) and then waitFor that Process to finish before calling System.exit - which certainly isn't mandatory. Something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // String command = "/usr/bin/sleep 5";
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add("c:/cygwin/bin/sleep");
    command.add("5");
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    BufferedReader is = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting command " + command);
        Process p = pb.start();

        int ret = p.waitFor();
        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        if (ret == 0) {
            System.out.println("Command has completed.");
            System.exit(ret);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Command completed with return code " + ret);
            System.exit(ret);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Caught Exception " + e.getMessage()
                + " running command " + command);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("COMMAND FAILED");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Will this get the output from the process to the console?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for process completion, you should also read all output (stdout **and** stderr) from the process you are starting.

If you call exit() after exec(), Java will do just that - exit immediatedly.

Here is an article that explains Runtime.exec pitfalls: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4 (also consider the other pages).

Comment: Just to add some color, call ``Prc.waitFor()``.  Get rid of the sleep, that is a timing error waiting to happen.